# Making client respond continuously to messages from server

Tags: c, client-server

I'm writing a simple client/server application and am having trouble getting the client to continuously respond to (at the moment, echo) messages sent to it.

**client.c**

```
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int ctrlsockfd;

void error(const char *message);
void closeStreams();
void writeResponse(const char *message);

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    printf("Client\n");

    // Connection code snipped

    // Handle responses
    int bytes_read;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    while (1) {
        // Fetch a message
        bytes_read = read(ctrlsockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE);

        if (bytes_read == -1) {
            error("Failed to read");
        }

        // Send it back
        if (write(ctrlsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1) == -1) {
            error("Failed to write");
        }
    }

    // Disconnect
    closeStreams();

    return 0;
}
```

**host.c**

```
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define LISTENPORT 9735

void closeStreams();
void error(const char *message);

int ctrlsockfd, clientsockfd;

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    printf("Server\n");

    // Connection code snipped

    // Accept a request (blocking) - we can only connect to one client at a time
    clientlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
    clientsockfd = accept(ctrlsockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, (socklen_t*) &clientlen);
    if (clientsockfd == -1) {
        error("Error accepting");
    }

    while (1) {
        // Read input string from stdin
        printf("> ");
        char message[BUF_SIZE];
        if (scanf("%s", message) == -1) {
            error("Failed to read from terminal");
        }

        // Send to client
        if (write(clientsockfd, message, strlen(message) + 1) == -1) {
            error("Failed to send message");
        } else {
            printf("Sent message %s\n", message);
        }

        // Read response from client
        char response[BUF_SIZE];
        if (read(clientsockfd, response, BUF_SIZE) == -1) {
            error("Error reading response");
        } else {
            printf("Response: %s\n", response);
        }

        // Close the connection
        closeStreams();
    }
}
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you confuse server and client here. Usually the **server** listens to a port and waits for messages and then respond to them. **Also, the accept() needs to be part of the loop if you close the connection in each iteration, or alternatively, don't close the connection**.

```
Server       client
wait
             connect
             send data
read data
send data
             read data
<maybe iteration of send / receive here >
close        close
wait
...
```

Comment: Yes, in my case I need to reverse the roles, so you could just switch the names - I also only need to listen to one client's requests.

Comment: @Ross - ok, still, note that you close the connection at the end of the server loop for some reason, if you want to continue sending data, you shouldn't close the connection.

Comment: Ah, that was the problem - thank you for your help (and on the other question)!

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a bit more wrong here, but right away I'd do this:

```
// Send it back
if (bytes_read > 0 && write(ctrlsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1) == -1) {
     error("Failed to write");
}
```

Kinda wonder what those writes when nothing was read were doing...

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I wasn't thinking about this properly - I assumed read would block until it had read bytes in.

Comment: I don't know you're exact environment, but at some point the socket read is going to timeout and return a timeout error.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent that (i.e. no timeout) or a better pattern I should use?